# Testing python classes which leverage class attributes

Tags: python, class, oop, pytest

I have a python class which uses class variables to maintain some instance-wide state. However, when attempting to test various scenarios via pytest I'm realizing that the class-level attributes are being shared across the tests since it's the same interpreter being used. Is there any pattern or way around this outside of running each class as a separate invocation of the `pytest` command or resetting every class attribute manually between tests? It's looking like a big no but wanted to ask and make sure.

p.s. For those who will immediately ask why I'm using class attributes. I'm using class attributes for state because this code will run on AWS Lambda. With this pattern I can cache objects in memory as class-attributes between lambda invocations and be assured that instance attributes are cleared each time the lambda runs. It's an attempt at using some OOP and writing base lambda classes with logging and various helpers already implemented that other devs can leverage

Comment: You can write an autouse fixture that will reset the class attributes to its default values.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/imp.html#imp.reload

> When reload(module) is executed:
>
> Python modules’ code is recompiled and the module-level code
> reexecuted, defining a new set of objects which are bound to names in
> the module’s dictionary. The init function of extension modules is not
> called a second time. As with all other objects in Python the old
> objects are only reclaimed after their reference counts drop to zero.
> The names in the module namespace are updated to point to any new or
> changed objects. Other references to the old objects (such as names
> external to the module) are not rebound to refer to the new objects
> and must be updated in each namespace where they occur if that is
> desired.